# In MediaToolkit output file not saved in the specified directory path in the asp.net core with docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

When I try to convert video using **MediaToolkit** in the local system, then it's working fine, but the same project when I run in **docker** then output file not saved in the given path.

Also, the output file is not saved in the directory so I am getting null metadata.

**Here is my code**

```
using (var engine = new Engine())
 {
    engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile, conversionOptions);
    engine.GetMetadata(outputFile);
    engine.Dispose();
 }
    
FileInfo outputFileInfo = new FileInfo(outputFile.Filename);
```

**Error** - Could not find file '/app/e77f2017-ef6e-4115-ba00-73a5c09941a9.mp4'

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

check the current path (you are working relative)
the program might not run from you think and then "app" directory is not found.

Comment: Where should I change in code? In Dockerfile for my project?

Comment: in your code. you can add your docker file here , it will be very helpful